# Python 3 Functions not defined until run in a different part of the code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I have just been programming in python, and have been looking to just make simple programs to start getting a better understanding.

I am busy writing a rock paper scissors text game and to work out the games winner/looser etc I created a function. For a while I when I ran my program I kept getting an error when the function was called, it was that my function was not defined. My function was below my initial code.

However I for some reason moved my function to the top of my code under my global variable declarations, and now my function executes perfectly.

Why is this the case? is there a way I can have my functions below my main code but not get the error of my function being undefined. Would I just need to declare my function before and then call it later, if so, how would I declare an empty function?

I would love to understand so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: where is the code you are trying to run? Please add it to the question

Comment: Functions cannot be called before they have been defined. Often scripts have a `main` function that calls other functions, and the call to `main()` is at the very end of the script, so it is reached after everything has been defined.

Answer (score 1):

> Why is this the case?

Because that's the way Python works - all the code at the top-level of a module or script is executed sequentially, so functions are only defined *after* the `def` statement has been executed.

You have to understand that in Python everything is an object, including functions, classes etc, so the `def` statement is mostly a syntactic sugar that creates a function object (from the `def` block) and binds it to the function name, IOW a function is just another global variable in your module or script - and you wouldn't expect to be able to use a variable before you defined it, would you ?

> is there a way I can have my functions below my main code but not get the error of my function being undefined.

Yes quite simply by putting your "main code" in a function and call this function at the end of the script:

```
import something
import another thing

def main():
    bar = foo()
    print("the answer is {}".format(bar))

def foo():
    return 42


# this makes sure the main function will only be executed
# when using your .py file as a script, not when importing
# it as a module.    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation I really appreciate you taking the time and explaining it so simply.

Answer (score 0):

Function has to be defined first before it is called.You have to define a function and afterwards function can be called anywhere in the program.

This is how Python works,in this all the things executes in a sequence.